# using timer inside a loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface, timer, error-handling, matlab-guide

My GUI's aim is to show images and to get a response from the user: either a key press (E or I) or no response. Between the images themselves there should be a 3 second pause showing some text (`a7 UIcontrol` in my code). The problem is that I need to do it for 30 times, so I use a loop with a timer inside it. But  the GUI works badly..

It should do the following:

```
for 30 times do
    2 sec showing text (a7)
    then showing an image for 3 sec or until I\E are pressed
end
```

This is my code; I am adding two versions, because they differ mostly in the TIMER functions and properties..

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N6LSDAYo_DVrBCUbuPth4JPCvkI3pBNcnAZcV6Kl9wM/edit
more readable version: http://pastebin.com/vd3HNGv1

and the photos are here (although you can use any 2 photos): https://picasaweb.google.com/alex.goltser/ScrapbookPhotos

At first the problem was always an error:

> you try to start the timer while it works

But now it is something else..

Answer (score 0):

Why run timer functions at all?

Here's an other way how you could run your loop:

```
for repeat = 1:30

    *show text*
    drawnow %# to make sure the graphics are updated
    pause(2) %# wait two seconds

    *show image*
    drawnow
    t = tic;
    done = false;
    while ~done && toc(t)<3 %# checks for keypress or until 3 secs
       *check for keypress*
       if E/I key has been pressed
          done = true;
       end
    end
end %# repeat 30x
```

Comment: I tried using your idea- but it does'nt work, first of all - I have  a KeyPressFcn in my figure properties, but what should I write instead of- " if keypress"? because I have no output in my keypress function, it just key_press(~,eventdata)..

Comment: @user1742463: I apologize for the confusion. `keypress` doesn't refer to the Matlab function, but to `whether a key has been pressed`. You do this with the java.robot class, in your code, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @user1742463: actually, you could check whether `get(figureHandle,'currentCharacter') is either `E` or `I` in the *check for keypress* line.

Comment: I get this error while running- "Undefined function or variable 'figureHandle'." what could be the problem? I use mainly UIcontrols instead of handles. so you have any idea what to change ?

Comment: @user1742463: `figureHandle` is the handle to the parent figure of all your uicontrols. It's `fh` in your code.

Comment: yea, thats what I did...  but  now it stoped loading the images up.. I have'nt touched any thing else.. thats weird. my code looks now like this, but somehow it still does'nt work- [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q83Us8kpUKApliBNhuKyPdaWDc1DTwAUy8pMPfYqJjA/edit)

Comment: maybe I should mention in the properties the parent \children thing , because I have'nt..